# Online learning with strongly convex loss w.r.t. L1 norm

Tags: optimization, online-algorithms

Consider an online learning problem where the loss function observed by the algorithm at time $t$ can be written as

$$
f_t(\lambda) = \langle V_t, w \rangle + \mu \sum \lambda_i \log \lambda_i
$$
for some $\mu\geq 0$, $V_t\in [0, L]^d$ and $\lambda$ is in a probability simplex.

It is easy to see that $f_t(\lambda)$ is $\mu$-strongly convex w.r.t L1-norm. I am wondering if there is any online learning algorithm to give a fast rate on the regret defined as

$$
Regret = \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(\lambda_t) - \min_{\lambda\in \Delta} \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(\lambda)
$$
where $\Delta$ is the probability simplex over dimension $d$, that is, $\Delta = [p\in [0,1]^d | \sum p_i =1]$.

Comment: Yes, $\mu$ is non-negative and the regularizer is the negative Shannon entropy.

Comment: Why not include such information in the question itself?

Comment: It is mostly implied when we say $\mu$-strongly convex. Strongly convex with negative $\mu$ won't make any sense. I added the constraints for clarity.